Is possible to add external dependencies at my own birt project build?
I've been trying to migrate the birt to be compatible with jakarta 10 for the past few days, but I am dealing with a problem:
I need to add some jakarta related dependencies (like "jakarta.servlet-api" artifact) since I am going to replace the javax to jakarta. So what I actually need to do is to add the required dependencies into the compile classpath so that it will be compiled successfully.
The problem is that if I try to add these dependencies in pom xml, they are being downloaded successfully during the build but they aren't added in the classpath. I found that since the project uses tycho plugin and feature.xml files, it doesn't add the files in the class path so arises a compilation error.

Sounds like you have an Eclipse RCP built with tycho. Everything in an RCP must be in a plugin (or the Java JRE). Eclipse Orbit [https://github.com/eclipse-orbit#update-sites] provides plug-ins for the Jakarta code.

I am completely no familiar with this build tools and philosophy. So can I add this to my project and then insert add plugins regarding my requirements? (I mean about Jakarta code).

You would normally add the Orbit update site to the target platform and add the plug-in dependencies to your plug-ins in the MANIFEST.MF
